# swagger-maven-plugin is not generating @ApiResponse schemes

Tags: maven, swagger, openapi

I'm using the swagger-maven-plugin to generate the YAML and JSON files on compilation as follows:

```
   <plugin>
    <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7</version>
    <configuration>
      <outputFileName>openapi</outputFileName>
      <outputPath>${project.build.directory}/openapi</outputPath>
      <outputFormat>JSONANDYAML</outputFormat>
      <resourcePackages>
        <package>mypackage.rest</package>
      </resourcePackages>
      <prettyPrint>true</prettyPrint>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>resolve</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Both files are being generated but the 'responses' are being defaulted:

```
"/transactions/{id}" : {
  "get" : {
    "operationId" : "getSingleTransaction",
    "parameters" : [ {
      "name" : "id",
      "in" : "path",
      "required" : true,
      "schema" : {
        "type" : "string"
      }
    } ],
    "responses" : {
      "default" : {
        "description" : "default response",
        "content" : {
          "application/vnd.oracle.resource+json;type=singular" : { }
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
```

However, in the Java class file, it's annotated with the @ApiResponse keyword:

```
@GET
@Operation(summary = "Get collection of Transactions for the given transactionId",
        description = "Get collection of Transactions for the given transactionId")
@APIResponse(description = "A list of TransactionDto",
        content = @Content(mediaType = APPLICATION_JSON,
                schema = @Schema(type = ARRAY, implementation = TransactionDto.class)))
@Consumes(APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(COLLECTION)
public Response getApprovalTasksForTransactionId(
        @PathParam("transactionId") TransactionId transactionId) {

    ...
}
```

Notice that the 'ProductsDto' is part of the ApiResponse but the YAML definition defaults it.

What could I be missing to correctly map the response and the response type scheme?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that my annotations in the java file were imported from:

```
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations
```

And figured out that the swagger-maven-plugin needs the following annotations instead
:

```
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations
```